# Plotting spatial data on a heatmap

Tags: python, numpy, text, heatmap, spatial

I have a challenging problem that I have not figured out yet. So, I have a bunch of data from a fluid flow simulation. I have two files: the spatial (x,y,z) data, which looks like this (note, I only care about 2D, so only the x and y values):

```
(-2 -1.5 0.1)
(5 -1.5 0.1)
(-2 -1.5 0.6)
(5 -1.5 0.6)
(-2 1.92708 0.1)
...
```

and its corresponding velocity_magnitude values. where each line corresponds to the velocty_x at the location in the spatial data file. For example, the value 0.08 is at (-2 -1.5 0.1).

```
0.08 
0.07
0.1 
0.34 ...
...
```

I want to make this into a heat map. I naively first just focused on the velocity data, reformatted into a 2D array, and showed that heatmap but the locations are all wrong. The problem is the spatial data is not in order, so doing it my way did not work. How do I combine both the x,y location with the actual velocity value to create a heatmap for my data?

Comment: I guess you want to assess velocity mean at each pixel of the heatmap

Comment: you have the same (x,y) coord multiple times, you need to decide which one you want. Most likely your spatial data is not nice spaced so you need to resample/interpolate. Create an array for the heatmap and place the samples on the array and draw the heatmap

Comment: I have added alternative to render data and a commodity to import files, let me know if it addressed your question. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are interested in rendering mean velocity on the heatmap Matplotlib, Numpy and Scipy are packages of interest. Let's investigate some options you have...

### Data Visualisation

#### Trial Dataset

First we create a trial dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as mtri
   
# Create trial dataset:
N = 10000
a = np.array([-10, -10, 0])
b = np.array([15, 15, 0])
x0 = 3*np.random.randn(N, 3) + a
x1 = 5*np.random.randn(N, 3) + b
x = np.vstack([x0, x1])
v0 = np.exp(-0.01*np.linalg.norm(x0-a, axis=1)**2)
v1 = np.exp(-0.01*np.linalg.norm(x1-b, axis=1)**2)
v = np.hstack([v0, v1])

# Render dataset:
axe = plt.axes(projection='3d')
axe.plot_trisurf(x[:,0], x[:,1], v, cmap='jet', alpha=0.5)
axe.set_xlabel("x")
axe.set_ylabel("y")
axe.set_zlabel("Speed")
axe.view_init(elev=25, azim=-45)
```

It looks like:

[image]

#### 2D Hexagonal Histogram

The easiest way is probably to use Matplotlib [hexbin](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin.html) function:

```
# Render hexagonal histogram:
pc = plt.hexbin(x[:,0], x[:,1], C=v, gridsize=20)
pc.axes.set_title("Heatmap")
pc.axes.set_xlabel("x")
pc.axes.set_ylabel("y")
pc.axes.set_aspect("equal")
cb = plt.colorbar(ax=pc.axes)
cb.set_label("Speed")
```

It renders:

[image]

#### 2D Rectangular Histogram

You can also use [`numpy.histogram2D`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) and Matplolib [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html):

```
# Bin Counts:
c, *_ = np.histogram2d(x[:,0], x[:,1], bins=20)
# Bin Weight Sums:
s, xbin, ybin = np.histogram2d(x[:,0], x[:,1], bins=20, weights=v)
lims = [xbin.min(), xbin.max(), ybin.min(), ybin.max()]

# Render rectangular histogram:
iax = plt.imshow((s/c).T, extent=lims, origin='lower')
iax.axes.set_title("Heatmap")
iax.axes.set_xlabel("x")
iax.axes.set_ylabel("y")
iax.axes.set_aspect("equal")
cb = plt.colorbar(ax=iax.axes)
cb.set_label("Speed")
```

It outputs:

[image]

### Linear Interpolation

As pointed out by `@rioV8`, your dataset seems to be spatially irregular. If you need to map it to a rectangular grid, you can use the [mutlidimensional linear interpolator of Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator).

```
from scipy import interpolate

# Create interpolator:
ndpol = interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator(x[:,:2], v)

# Create meshgrid:
xl = np.linspace(-20, 30, 20)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xl, xl)
lims = [xl.min(), xl.max(), xl.min(), xl.max()]

# Interpolate over meshgrid:
V = ndpol(list(zip(X.ravel(),Y.ravel()))).reshape(X.shape)

# Render interpolated speeds:
iax = plt.imshow(V, extent=lims, origin='lower')
iax.axes.set_title("Heatmap")
iax.axes.set_xlabel("x")
iax.axes.set_ylabel("y")
iax.axes.set_aspect("equal")
cb = plt.colorbar(ax=iax.axes)
cb.set_label("Speed")
```

It renders:

[image]

Nota: in this version ticks still need to be centered on each pixel.

#### Contours

Once you have a rectangular grid you can also draw Matplotlib [contours](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html):

```
# Render contours:
iax = plt.contour(X, Y, V)
iax.axes.set_title("Contours")
iax.axes.set_xlabel("x")
iax.axes.set_ylabel("y")
iax.axes.set_aspect("equal")
iax.axes.grid()
iax.axes.clabel(iax)
```

[image]

### Data Manipulation

Based on the file formats you provided, it is easy to import it using pandas:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
    
with open("spatial.txt") as fh:
    file1 = io.StringIO(fh.read().replace("(", "").replace(")", ""))
x = pd.read_csv(file1, sep=" ", header=None).values

v = pd.read_csv("speed.txt", header=None).squeeze().values
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! It was very helpful and it worked.

Comment: @smokbel_06 I am glad it worked, you may mark it as an answer if you think it is appropriate. Cheers